# What is the TX key?

Tags: transaction-data, transaction-hash, transaction-key, transaction-generation

What is the TX key?

I know it is related to $r$ from the whitepaper, but I'm not sure which number it is. (I'm thinking it is either r, rA, or H(rA)).

Answer (score 5):

The private tx key is named *r* in the [CryptoNote whitepaper](https://cryptonote.org/whitepaper.pdf). Note that *r* is randomly chosen. In addition, the private tx key can be used as prove of payment on a case by case basis. That is, in case of a dispute, you can prove that you paid the receiver by publishing the private tx key (which you can obtain from the wallet), the transaction ID, and the receiver's address. An auditor can subsequently verify that you paid the receiver.

The public tx key, which is embedded into tx_extra, is *R*, where R = rG. This graph of luigi1111, which is originally from the [CryptoNote whitepaper](https://cryptonote.org/whitepaper.pdf), might be helpful too:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7UXE.png

Comment: You can strip the steemit stuff out... :)
Oh, and a quibble. Revealing r doesn't prove that *you* paid someone, only that that someone has received money. In practice, in an actual dispute, you'd be referencing a particular destination and TXID to a 3rd party, which would come much closer to proving to said 3rd party that you paid the recipient in question.

Comment: One could also sign a message with 'r' to avoid disclosing it?