# How can I get a transaction history of sent and received transfers for my account?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, transaction-data

I'm on Monero 'Wolfram Warptangent' (v0.10.0.0-release) and I need to get a complete transaction history of my single account. How can this be done with Monero? Can the cli wallet do this for me?

Answer (score 2):

This is simply done by entering the `show_transfers` command into `monero-wallet-cli`. It will show the blockheight, in/out, date, transaction hash, recipient address (outgoing transfers only), amount, fee (outgoing transfers only), and payment ID. If you also want to obtain the [private tx keys](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/1651/what-is-the-tx-key/1652#1652) you have to enter the `get_tx_key <transaction hash>` command into `monero-wallet-cli`.

Comment: What if it is empty? The wallet just has been restored from seed phrase, and "export_transfers out 0" command gives an empty list! How to get all previous Monero transactions?

Comment: @Catherine - Does `show_transfers` display any transactions?

Comment: all transactions are shown when blockchain done its synchronization. I have one more question:  where the "tx key" are stored in the blockchain or on local computer? What will be happened with "tx key"  in case of restoration from seed phrase on new computer?

Comment: All right. The transaction keys are stored locally in the wallet cache (the wallet file without extension). Thus, they are not retrievable in case of a restore from the mnemonic seed procedure on a different system. You can, however, restore them by simply copying the wallet cache to the new / other system.