# How do I export my transaction history from wallet CLI in a usable format (.txt, .csv, etc.)?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli

Taken from [/r/MoneroSupport](https://www.reddit.com/r/monerosupport/comments/6yuh0l/how_do_i_export_my_transaction_history_from/):

I'm having trouble exporting my wallet transaction history from monero-wallet-cli.exe into a usable format. I'm using Windows 7 and v0.10.3.1-release. "show_transfers" prints out all the info I need into the console, but I can't figure out a way to copy-paste it into a .txt file or output it in any other way.

I tried "show_transfers >> txns.txt" but got this error: "Error: Bad min_height parameter: >>"

I found this, which doesn't get me any further than I already am: [How can I get a transaction history of sent and received transfers for my account?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/2664/how-can-i-get-a-transaction-history-of-sent-and-received-transfers-for-my-accoun)

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
monero-wallet-cli --command "show_transfers" --wallet-file=/path/to/wallet --password 'password' >> my_txns.txt
```

The output is not CSV though.

Here is a bit of commandline hacking to make into CSV:

```
monero-wallet-cli --command "show_transfers" --wallet-file=/path/to/wallet --password 'password' | egrep '^ '| sed 's/^ //g'| sed 's/ \+/,/g' >> my_txns.csv
```

(only tested with a watch-only wallet)

Comment: I tried your code above with my information but keep getting the error below Error: usage: show_transfers [in|out|all|pending|failed] [<min_height> [<max_height>]] I have tried adding that information but cant seem to get it to work. Do you have any idea to fix that error?

Comment: Error: usage: show_transfers [in|out|all|pending|failed] [<min_height> [<max_height>]]

Answer (score 1):

You can now do this with the `export_transfers` command in the CLI (0.13 and later):

https://github.com/monero-project/monero/pull/4236