# Recent Transaction Cannot Be Found

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, synchronization

I recently sent Monero from my GUI wallet to an associates GUI wallet and the funds never arrived. I followed all the processes on your thread here:

[How do I, as a sender, verify that my transaction actually arrived?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/6134/how-do-i-as-a-sender-verify-that-my-transaction-actually-arrived?rq=1)

and the funds STILL do not show in the recipients wallet. I have deleted the blockchain, resynced the whole blockchain, switched to a remote node, resynced the wallet multiple times, and used the tool at:

https://xmr.llcoins.net/checktx.html

which shows the message: "Failed to get transaction data! Your Tx Hash probably doesn't exist. When I check the transaction via my sending GUI wallet, it tells me the funds were sent to the correct address and have been verified over 3000 times. I really don't understand what's going on.

The sending wallet uses v0.11.1 and the receiving wallet uses v0.12.0 of the GUI wallet. Both machines use Mac OS X.

Just found out the Monero had a hard fork on April 6th from reading this article:

[I forgot to upgrade (from CLI or GUI v0.11 to CLI or GUI v0.12) and, as a result, accidentally synced to the wrong (alternative) chain](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/7989/i-forgot-to-upgrade-from-cli-or-gui-v0-11-to-cli-or-gui-v0-12-and-as-a-result)

My associates v0.12.0 GUI wallet was just created a week ago, after the fork. My wallet was running v0.11.1 GUI wallet when the funds were sent and had been running a full node with the blockchain stored locally...the pre-fork blockchain. Seems that he funds were sent to the old chain and my associates wallet has the blocks in it from the new, post April 6th, chain.

How can this be checked and/or corrected?

Can you assist me in further troubleshooting/research into this missing transaction? I have access to both wallets and can do whatever it takes.

In appreciation,
jason

Comment: @muk3sh - You're, probably, synced to the wrong (alternative) chain. Therefore, you should be able to resolve your issue with that ^ guide. Please note: 

"As a general rule of thumb, for each day you synced after the fork height (1546000 or April 6) you have to pop 800 blocks. Thus, let's say you synced 10 days on the wrong (alternative) chain, you should use --pop-blocks 8000" | Since we're 25 days after the scheduled network upgrade, you ought to use `--pop-blocks 20000`.

Comment: @muk3sh - P.S. I reckon aforementioned guide might be a bit convoluted. Therefore, if you need any assistance, feel free to shoot me a PM on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/user/dEBRUYNE_1/) or on [IRC](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/8bt9mn/monero_help/dx9g491/). P.P.S. Your funds should show up after you've applied aforementioned guide.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I just finished with the resync and my monero showed up as if nothing had happened. Thanks for the suggestions and support. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're still synced to the wrong chain. You'll need to download the latest GUI wallet (v0.12.0) from here: https://getmonero.org/downloads/  When you have allowed the new wallet time to sync, you will likely find your funds in your wallet and that they have not been sent.  You can then send them to your recipient safe in the knowledge that you and your recipient are using the same current blockchain.

You can get more info from the guide you've already mentioned above: 
[I forgot to upgrade (from CLI or GUI v0.11 to CLI or GUI v0.12) and, as a result, accidentally synced to the wrong (alternative) chain](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/7989/i-forgot-to-upgrade-from-cli-or-gui-v0-11-to-cli-or-gui-v0-12-and-as-a-result)  Following this guide should resolve your problem.