# Sent Monero to Atomic Swap Wallet using GUI Wallet - Slow Transaction

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

I sent some Monero to an Atomic Swap wallet using GUI Wallet and the Transaction is still pending after 24 hours. I can see the block confirmations is moving very slowly. Can someone help me on this? I'm using Windows 10.

[image]

Comment: Where does it show `Pending`? Because your screenshot shows that the transaction has 1092 confirmations.

Comment: It hasn't arrived in my Atomic Swap wallet yet and it's been more than 24 hours. The Transaction is still red and the confirmations are going up very very slowly. Any idea why it's so slow?

https://localmonero.co/blocks/search/72eb9cda9922676586e97a08e50052f7fc25357d93c9a97035c5ddab16274c9b

Comment: Red simply means that it is an outgoing transaction. Can you verify the transaction first? https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/6134/how-do-i-as-a-sender-verify-that-my-transaction-actually-arrived

Comment: Hi, I just tried verifying the transaction by following the instructions for your previous link but I can't seem to find my private key on GUI. Transactions and clicked on Transaction Key (Click to Reveal) and it's blank.

How do I verify the transaction. Where can I find the Private Key?

Comment: Does this help?
https://minergate.com/blockchain/xmr/transaction/72eb9cda9922676586e97a08e50052f7fc25357d93c9a97035c5ddab16274c9b

Comment: I just checked Show seed & Keys and the Secret View Key is all zeroes.

Comment: Are you using the GUI in conjunction with a Ledger or Trezor device?

Comment: Yes I'm using a Nano Ledger. I have to connect it before I log into the GUI. I still haven't received my monero in the atomic swap yet. Have I lost my money?

Comment: I just tried restoring my atomic swap wallet and I still haven't received anything. I have no idea what has happened.

Comment: How did you try to restore it? I did notice that Atomic Wallet has been having some issues with their Monero integration, which may be the reason for your issue.

Comment: I just restored from back up. If Atomic Wallet is having issues with Monero then I will wait and contact them. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I just fixed it. It was an issue with Atomic Swap this whole time. I'm sorry for wasting your time. Have a good day Sir/

Comment: Don't worry about it and you too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just got an email from Atomic Swap support and they said the following.

"XMR is under maintenance in Atomic Wallet due to the incompatibility with the new update. You won't be able to send, exchange, and possibly see your balance. Our team is working on the issue, but there is no ETA."

Issues has been resolved.